# Copy File(s) From Local Machine to AWS EC2 CoreOS Machine(s) Via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, coreos

I am trying to copy some file(s) over from my local box to a created CoreOS machine via Terraform (in a "main.tf" file).  I have tried different permutations of the provisioner block to no avail.  For example, for this I get "unable to authenticate" when I nest this block inside a resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "myfoo" {...} block:

```
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "foo.txt"
    destination = "/etc/foo.txt"

    connection {
      user     = "root"
      private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/mykeyfile.pem")}"
    }
  }
```

The error I get is:

```
...
aws_autoscaling_group.myfoo: Still creating... (30s elapsed)
aws_autoscaling_group.myfoo: Provisioning with 'file'...
aws_autoscaling_group.myfoo: Still creating... (40s elapsed)
...
aws_autoscaling_group.myfoo: Still creating... (5m10s elapsed)
aws_autoscaling_group.myfoo: Still creating... (5m20s elapsed)
aws_autoscaling_group.myfoo: Still creating... (5m30s elapsed)

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_autoscaling_group.myfoo: 1 error(s) occurred:

* ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

The file(s) are security files, and I don't want to bake them into a Docker image.  Also, since they are security files I don't want to use write_files in the cloud-config.template.yaml to write them out.  Perhaps there is another way to do this within the Cloud Config? Thanks.

Comment: The user doesn't have the ssh key, probably you want to use other user like "ubuntu" or "ec2-user", show the instance definition.

Comment: If you're creating an autoscaling group how are you providing the IP addresses of the instances to connect to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using CoreOS the default username is `core` not `root`

https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-ec2.html

The Key needs to exist in AWS as well before you can use it, so you can assign to the instance.

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeyfile" {
  key_name   = "mykeyfile"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQD3F6tyPEFEzV0LX3X8BsXdMsQz1x2cEikKDEY0aIj41qgxMCP/iteneqXSIFZBp5vizPvaoIR3Um9xK7PGoW8giupGn+EPuxIA4cDM4vzOqOkiMPhz5XK0whEjkVzTo4+S0puvDZuwIsdiW9mxhJc7tgBNL0cYlWSYVkz4G/fslNfRPW5mYAM49f4fhtxPb5ok4Q2Lg9dPKVHO/Bgeu5woMc7RY0p1ej6D4CKFE6lymSDJpW0YHX/wqE9+cfEauh7xZcG0q9t2ta6F6fmX0agvpFyZo8aFbXeUBr7osSCJNgvavWbM/06niWrOvYX2xwWdhXmXSrbX8ZbabVohBK41 email@example.com"
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/key_pair.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#key_name

Also if you are using autoscaling, I would place that file in an S3 bucket and give the instance role access to that s3 bucket, if an instance is replaced by the ASG it won't have access to that local file. Or use something like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) or [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/) for the config file.

Comment: Thanks.  Going the S3 bucket route and pulling the files down through AWS CLI in the Cloud Config has proved fruitful and successfully addresses my scenario.  I think you are correct in that a file provisioner was not the correct approach for an ASG.

Comment: Glad I could help point you in the right direction. If you could accept that answer that would be appreciated.